# Ubuntu 12.04 USB keyboard stopped working

Tags: usb, keyboard

After an upgrade to 12.04, my USB port stopped identifying my usb keyboard logitech K120.  I have switched keyboard and mouse to ensure that USB port is working.

The mouse works perfect but keyboard does not work on another usb port either. I plugged the USB keyboard to another computer it works fine.  Somehow, after 12.04 upgrade, Ubuntu stops recognizing USB keyboard on a laptop AMILO Fujitsu Siemens.

Any advise please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer to your question, but I had the same problem and I solved it by upgrading further to 13.10.  It was nasty for me because I had no PS/2.

I used a different system to downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 and made an install key.  Then I booted my broken system off that 12.10 key.  The keyboard and mouse worked, so I chose the upgrade 10 12.10.  Once I upgraded and removed the 12.10 installer key, the keyboard and mouse stopped working.

But then I did the same procedure but with version 13.10. This time it worked.